# Averaging averages without losing standard deviation information

Tags: statistics, average, standard-deviation

I've got a computerized procedure which runs a test and takes a few hundred samples during testing.  When finished, it spits back out the average and standard deviation of the samples.

Now, I've run this test several times on test subjects that should be identical, but of course I get back slightly different average and standard deviation data each time.  I only have a record of the average and standard deviation returned at the end of the test, not of each individual sample point.  A typical data set will look something like the following:

```
SUBJECT   AVG     STD
      1   129.2   31.0
      2   125.0   37.3
      3   123.6   34.7
      4   130.1   31.3
     ...   ...    ...
```

Now, if I just average together the averages I get 127.0, but the standard deviation is only 3.2, when in fact the standard deviation between any actual samples is likely to be closer to 30.  Is there a way I can combine my summary statistics that preserves the information I have about the standard deviation between samples?

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the size of the data sets which generated the outputs above (it's somewhere around a hundred points, but is different each time and not something I have access to records of).

Comment: You want (roughly speaking) the average of the standard deviations, not the standard deviation of the standard deviations (and certainly not the standard deviation of the averages).

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicate of above linked.  Unlike that question, the size of the data set generated for each subject is unknown here.  It's roughly on the order of 100 points, but the exact number differs for each set.  The accepted answer makes extensive use of this knowledge (which I don't have).

Comment: You can't exactly calculate the overall standard deviation without knowing the size of each subsample. You can only estimate it by guessing the sample size. This should be intuitive: if I have one sample of 100 things and another sample of 10000 things, and they're from the same distribution, the standard deviation of the second should be about 10 times smaller than the standard deviation of the first. I have to take that into account to get a reasonable standard deviation of the whole group of 10100 things.

Comment: There's something fundamentally flawed about a computerized procedure that reports the mean and standard deviation but provides no way to know the sample size. Why would anyone create software like that?

Comment: Ok, so if the number of samples is "close enough," can we just combine the standard deviations with an average like TonyK suggested (essentially assuming they are all from exactly the same number of samples)?  Is there a way to know how close "close enough" would be to give an estimated std that doesn't differ more than, say, 10% from the standard deviation we would expect to get with different sample sizes?

Comment: (@DavidK it might actually report the sample sizes, I would have to check, but I'm looking at hand-recorded data right now that was copied from the output and all I have are the average and standard deviations)

Comment: You can try to crunch it out, but it'll be tricky, the exact sensitivity to the values of $n_{x_i}$ depends on the values of $\overline{x}_i$ and $s_{x_i}$.

Comment: OK, omitting the sample size from the handwritten copy of the software output is a lot more believable. Anyway, if you're curious about how much the SD depends on the sample sizes, you could try putting the method from the other question's answer in a spreadsheet using estimated sample sizes and see how much you can change the final SD by setting some sample sizes to the smallest likely size and others to the largest likely size (e.g., large samples with high SD and small samples with low SD will tend to pull the SD up).

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to estimate population mean and SD, and assuming
the sample sizes are equal, then you can get by with estimates based on
averages. Averaging the $\bar X$s estimates the population mean.

To estimate the population SD:
(1) square the SDs to get variances
(2) average the variances
(3) take the square root

In R, for the numbers you gave:

```
SD = c(31.0, 37.3, 34.7, 31.3)
sqrt(mean(SD^2))
## 33.67518
```

This is *not* quite the same thing as the SD of all the observations combined.

Roughly speaking, the loss in efficiency in estimating the population
SD is like losing one observation for each of the separate SDs. Maybe
not important if sample sizes are large.

This is based on the method of getting a combined estimate of 
variance from variances in each of the groups in a one-factor analysis 
of variance (ANOVA). You can look up the formulas there.

Comment: To be clear, you mean that the loss of accuracy in SD is as if each specimen (of which there are only a few) lost one of its samples (of which there are roughly 100 per specimen)?

Comment: This actually works, modulo the little off-by-one issues because of the $n-1$ in the formula for the sample standard deviation, provided that the sample means are all the same and the sample sizes are all the same (regardless of what they actually are). If either of these starts to deviate by a lot, then you will start having trouble. With the OP's numbers it looks like this will probably work fairly well.

Comment: Technically, we are talking about 'degrees of freedom' (df). Suppose, you have 10 samples of size 100. Then you would have 999 df for estimating the population variance from all 1000 observation. Using the 10 separate samples, there are 99 df for each sample and 990 for their avg.

Comment: And yes, @Ian, I _am_ assuming all samples are from the same process so that the population means and the population SDs are the same (as in a one-factor ANOVA under the null  hypothesis that all group pop means are equal).